# Appending int value to a bunch of list variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I am trying to append an int value to a bunch of list variables all at once. Is there a for loop or such a function that would allow me to do that? Like I would like to append the val int to all list variables defined below.

```
val = 100
list_1=[]
list_2=[]
list_3=[]
list_4= []
```

Comment: Yes, if your lists were all in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list containing all the lists, then use a loop:

```
val = 100
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
list_4 = []

list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4]

for li in list_of_lists:
    li.append(val)
```

**Caution**: do **not** be tempted to create `list_of_lists` in the following way:

```
list_of_lists = [[]] * 4
```

This will create a single list with 4 references to it, and changes done through 1 of them will be seen by all the other.

However, you **can** do

```
list_of_lists = [[] for _ in range(4)]

for li in list_of_lists:
    li.append(100)

print(list_of_lists)
# [[100], [100], [100], [100]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would prefer a function to do so, as it is likely you'll do this again.

```py
def appendAll(value, *args):
    for listItem in args:
        listItem.append(value)
```

This allows you to add a value to any set of lists. It doesn't require you to setup a list of variables as `*args` lets you pass any number of arguments and creates a tuple which lets us loop through each list and append our value to each list.

```py
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
val = []

#now we can append val to all the lists or some of them
appendAll(val, list1, list2, list3)
```